# looping through multiple attributes in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `has_many: skills` in my user model and I'm wondering, after a user has selected many skills in dynamically generated form fileds, how do I pull all the skills into an array and display them into my view?

Comment: Have the skills been persisted to the database when you want to show them or does this seem to be a javascript job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the skills been persisted yet?  If so, with that association, you should be able to get an array of a user's skills (assuming you have a user `@user`) with

```
@user.skills
```

Comment: tried that and I get `#<Skill:0x1030c4050>#<Skill:0x1030c1710>#<Skill:0x1030c15d0>#<Skill:0x1030c1490>#<Skill:0x1030c1350>#<Skill:0x1030c1210>#<Skill:0x1030c10d0>#<Skill:0x1030c0f90>#<Skill:0x1030c0e50>#<Skill:0x1030c0d10>#<Skill:0x1030c0bd0>#<Skill:0x1030c0a90>#<Skill:0x1030c0950>#<Skill:0x1030c07c0>#<Skill:0x1030c0680>#<Skill:0x1030c0540>#<Skill:0x1030c0400>#<Skill:0x1030c02c0>#<Skill:0x1030c0180>#<Skill:0x1030c0040>#<Skill:0x1030bff00>#<Skill:0x1030bfd70>` and when I do `@user.skills.name` I get 'Skill' and thats it.

Comment: `@user.skills` is an array.  What happens you call `@user.skills[0].name`?

Comment: that works, I also have an `experience` column. kinda a separate question but off the top of your head is there a way I can print out all `skill.name` values with `skill.experience` = 3, 2, etc... in separate lists?

Comment: `@user.skills.where(:experience => 3)` will give you an array of skills belonging to that user where experience is 3.  Then you can grab the names you want out of that list.

Comment: thanks a ton! and lastly, is there a way to sort the skill names alpha order?

Comment: @user.skills.where(:experience => 3).order('skills.name ASC')

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want to do... if not, please update your question with what output you're really looking for. Like @thefugal, I'm assuming skill has a name.

Since @user.skills is an array, you need to loop over each of them.

```
<ul>
  <% @user.skills.each do |skill| %>
    <li><%= skill.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```